# Combinatorics problems involving permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $A= \{ 1,2,3,...,n\}$ a set and $f:A \to A$ a permutation of the set A. We call a number $x \in \{ 2,3,...,n-1 \}$ special if $f(x)>\max \{f(x-1),f(x+1) \}$ or $f(x)<\min \{f(x-1),f(x+1) \}.$ Determine the number of permutation with odd number of special numbers.

Comment: I'd like to offer two more hints. (a) Would you expect the number of special elements to be odd, rather than even (or vice versa), and why (this goes into getting a sense of what you should try to show, similarly to what @Arthur suggested)? (b) In order to determine/influence the parity of the number of special elements, must you be able to discern whether each element is special (this might help proving your proposition once you come to suspect the correct answer)?

Comment: I thought at Inclusion and Exclusion principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: It’s clear that there are no such permutations when $n<3$, and $n=3$ turns out to be a special case easily handled by brute force, so assume that $n\ge 4$.

- Show that $f$ has an odd number of special numbers if and only if either $f(1)<f(2)$ and $f(n-1)>f(n)$, or $f(1)>f(2)$ and $f(n-1)<f(n)$. (I.e., $f$ must have an ascent at $1$ and a descent at $n-1$, or a descent at $n=1$ and an ascent at $n-1$.)
- If $f$ is any permutation of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $\hat f$ be the permutation of $[n]$ defined by interchanging the values of $f(1)$ and $f(2)$: $\hat f(1)=f(2)$, $\hat f(2)=f(1)$, and $\hat f(k)=f(k)$ if $3\le k\le n$. Show that the map $f\mapsto\hat f$ is a bijection on the set of permutations of $[n]$.
- Show that $f$ has an odd number of special numbers if and only if $\hat f$ has an even number of special numbers.
- Use the last two points to get a simple closed form for the number of permutations of $[n]$ with an odd number of permutations.

Alternatively, you can use the following slightly clumsier approach that starts with the same basic insight.

- Show that $f$ has an odd number of special numbers if and only if either $f(1)<f(2)$ and $f(n-1)>f(n)$, or $f(1)>f(2)$ and $f(n-1)<f(n)$.
- How many ways are there to choose $f(1),f(2),f(n-1)$, and $f(n)$ and order them to match the first bullet point?
- How many ways are there to choose the rest of $f$?

Now put the pieces together and simplify.

Comment: M.Scott Can you give me more hints in the second alternative?

Comment: @I.Stefan: I’d rather not say much more: that’s already breaking it down into pretty small pieces. For the second bullet point first ask yourself how many ways there are to choose the two numbers that will be $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ in one order or the other. Once those have been chosen, how many ways are there to choose $2$ more numbers to be $f(n-1)$ and $f(n)$ in one order or the other. In other words, so far you’re just choosing two disjoint pairs from $[n]$. Suppose that $n=9$ and you’ve chosen $3$ and $5$ for the first pair and $1$ and $8$ for the second pair. You can make $f(1)=3$ and ...

Comment: ... $f(2)=5$, or you can make $f(1)=5$ and $f(2)=3$. If you do the first of these, you ***must*** you assign set $f(8)=8$ and $f(9)=1$ in order to get a permutation with an odd number of special numbers; why? Similarly, if you set $f(1)=5$ and $f(2)=3$, you ***must*** set $f(8)=1$ and $f(9)=8$. It doesn’t matter how you assign the numbers $1,2,4,6,7$, and $9$ to $3,4,5,6$, and $7$, you’ll get a permutation with an odd number of special numbers; why? Finally, how many ways are there to make that assignment of the $5$ remaining numbers?

Comment: I get it know. Thank you so much.

Comment: @I.Stefan: You’re very welcome.

Comment: M.Scott How can I prove that f(1)<f(2) and f(n-1)>f(n) or opposite?

Comment: @I.Stefan: Think of the graphs of $f$. For $n=6$ and the permutation $256143$, for instance, the graph consists of the points $\langle 1,2\rangle$, $\langle 2,5\rangle$, $\langle 3,6\rangle$, and so on. Now connect adjacent points; you get a schematic of a mountain range. In this case the range rises in two steps to a peak at $\langle 3,6$, drops to a valley at $\langle 4,1$, and rises to another peak at $\langle 5,4\rangle$ before falling to its right endpoint at $\langle 6,3\rangle$. It has two peaks and one valley, for a total of $3$ special points. Now notice that special points ...

Comment: ... ***always*** alternate peaks and valleys. This means that if there are an odd number of them, either the first and last are both peaks, or the first and last are both valleys. (Why?) Now see what this says about the first and last ‘steps’ of the mountain range. Can they both go in the same direction, or must one rise and the other fall?

Comment: What if there is $x$ such that $f(x) \gt f(x+1) \gt f(x+2).$

Comment: @I.Stefan: There may well be; it makes no difference. That’s just the mirror image of what happened with $x=1$ in my example in the previous pair of comments: $f(1)<f(2)<f(3)$.

Comment: M.Scott The answer is ${n \choose 2} \times {n-2 \choose 2} \times (n-4)!$?

Comment: @I.Stefan: Almost: you’re missing a factor of $2$, because the first pair can be arranged with $f(1)<f(2)$ (in which case the last pair must be arranged in decreasing order), or it can be arranged with $f(1)>f(2)$ (in which case the last pair must be arranged in increasing order).